# How to merge dataframe in delta table involving insert, update and delete?

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I would like to populate delta table that contains some columns and one column has used as partition and other is "primary key" (gene). So, Dependend on the data it record must be inserted, updated or deleted, like this:

Delta table:

| disease | gene | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| colon cancer | abn1 | 0.12 |
| breast cancer | agt2 | 0.02 |
| colon cancer | zn1t | 0.69 |

Dataframe table with values that must be insert into the delta table:

| disease | gene | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| colon cancer | abn1 | 0.13 |
| colon cancer | sad3 | 0.56 |
| colon cancer | wasr | 0.78 |
| colon cancer | gfvc | 0.21 |
| breast cancer | qwa2 | 0.12 |
| breast cancer | cv4s | 0.21 |
| breast cancer | asxz | 0.34 |

Expected Delta table:

| disease | gene | value | expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| colon cancer | abn1 | 0.13 | update |
| colon cancer | sad3 | 0.56 | insert |
| colon cancer | wasr | 0.78 | insert |
| colon cancer | gfvc | 0.21 | insert |
| colon cancer | zn1t | 0.69 | delete |
| breast cancer | qwa2 | 0.12 | insert |
| breast cancer | cv4s | 0.21 | insert |
| breast cancer | asxz | 0.34 | insert |
| breast cancer | agt2 | 0.02 | delete |

Do you have an idea to do it?

I thought of using Merge command but I didn't to resolve the delete condition. Another solution is to delete the records before and then to apply merge for insert and update, but in this case, is it necessaty to apply them in the same transaction? Is there another solition?

Comment: Are you using Databricks or open source Delta Lake? Can you also describe a logic not only by data (for example, I don't see `breast cancer/agt2` in the resulting table, but I see `colon cancer/zn1t` two times)

Comment: Hi! I'm using spark and delta lake in my local machine. The example about the data was wrong. I updated the data. In your case, `breast cancer/agt2` must be deleted and `colon cancer/zn1t` is not duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of functionality is supported with the new `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause in the `MERGE` statement ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into.html)).  It was just released on Databricks as part of the [Databricks Runtime 12.1](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/12.1.html#support-for-when-not-matched-by-source-for-merge-into) and is slashed for release in upcoming version of OSS Delta - 2.3.0 (see corresponding [PR1](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/pull/1511), [PR2](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/pull/1533)).

If you can't wait for a new release, then you can proceed with using normal merge for existing values only (`WHEN MATCHED` without `WHEN NOT MATCHED`), and then do right join between table and incoming data, filter out not matched data, and perform delete operation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't wait for the new release. I implemented the second solution, Alex.
Thanks! It worked your solution, Alex!